# On what algorithm are implementations of Math.random based on?

Tags: javascript, random

Does the ECMAscript specification impose a specific pseudo-random generating algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't impose a specific algorithm, it depends on the implementation.

This is an interesting read on the topic: http://baagoe.org/en/w/index.php/Better_random_numbers_for_javascript

Comment: +1 for beating me to it and for the very good reference article.

Comment: +1 for beating me as well at pointing to the same article :-) Just voted to deleted my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the author broke his own website :/